# How to zero-extend a signed integer in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net

For example, I would like to assign `&H80000000` to a 64-bit signed integer variable:

```
Dim a As Long = &H80000000
```

However, integer `a` has value `&HFFFFFFFF80000000` instead of `&H80000000`. 
I tried to call `CULng` to circumvent the sign-extension. Nonetheless, it says "Constant expression not representable in type 'ULong'". I conjecture this is because Visual Basic prohibits a negative integer to be assigned to an unsigned variable.

I am using Visual Basic 2010 (.NET Framework 4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim a As Long = &H80000000L
```

Use the [literal suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters#literal-type-characters) `L` to tell the compiler that you intend this value to be a long literal. Otherwise, it's interpreted as a signed integer literal representing a negative value (`-2147483648`). Alternatively, you can use the suffix `UI` to denote an unsigned integer.

Example code:

```
Dim a As Long = &H80000000      ' Int32 literal -2147483648
Dim b As Long = &H80000000L     ' Int64 literal  2147483648
Dim c As Long = &H80000000UI    ' UInt32 literal 2147483648

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("X")) ' FFFFFFFF80000000
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X")) ' 80000000
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("X")) ' 80000000
```